# After closing modal, refreshing page doesn't load everything

Tags: javascript, css, modal-dialog

After I closed the modal and then refresh the page, my page doesn't load items that normally show up when you are on a certain spot of the page (for example: on 75% of the document length).

My website is http://www.bsrp.eu/tijdelijk/index.php, and if you go to contact> then click on `contact form> Close it with the cross> Refresh the page..` it wont show up the header and images. (till you scroll but thats because of my jquerys)

Someone knows were the problem is?

The modal is done with javascript and this is the code:

```
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');

var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

btn.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "block";
};

span.onclick = function () {
    modal.style.display = "none";
};

window.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

ofcourse with some css but I guess the problem is in the javascript

Comment: this might be right:  document.getElementById("myModel");

Comment: instead of `document.getElementById('myModal');` or just add it in the code? I tried both but it doesn't work.